# jQuery doesn't detect ų

Tags: javascript, jquery, character

I'm using jQuery highlight plugin to highlight.
As website is Lithuanian language based I need to detect word with diacritics even if user inputed word without them. I found out this `accent` option just this part doesn't work `'u': 'ų',`, even other letters works perfectly.

What can I do to be able to detect `ų` letter?

As in example plugin won't hightlight word `mokesčių` as you type `mokesciu`, because of the last `ų`
Example: [here](http://taxcard.lt/duk/)

```
var accentedForms = {
    'a': 'ą',
    'c': 'č',
    'e': 'ę',
    'e': 'ė',
    'i': 'į',
    's': 'š',
    'u': 'ų',
    'u': 'ū',
    'z': 'ž'
};

var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span', caseSensitive: false, wordsOnly: false, accentInsensitive: false };
jQuery.extend(settings, options);

if (settings.accentInsensitive) {
    for (var s in accentedForms) {
        words = words.replace(s, '[' + s + accentedForms[s] + ']');
    }
}
```

Comment: So I started to think about: http://jsbin.com/jareyutaxizo/5/edit It's in a bit of a mess... but you might be able to see where I was going.... Trying to just edit the plugin to make a list of all the possible combinations of the letters... with more time you could find tune it to be a recursive lookup...  I like this question, but it'd be a trick to edit.  I also thought that rather than doing a regex on everything like this, since this will get bloated pretty quick, it might be easier to modify the words that are found in the text you are searching... either way it would be a heavy load.